# SharePoint development with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i have installed SharePoint 2007 and VS2008 extension on my computer.i have created a site but i don't find source code for solution file.how i development for my SharePoint site on visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marcus' article is a good one. However I cannot recommend using Visual Studio Extensions for WSS (VSeWSS) due to the bugs and problems involved.

A good alternative is [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com). This community project integrates into Visual Studio makes it simple and easy to see exactly what you are doing and gives you control over how your code is deployed into SharePoint.

Also see the [Getting started developing for SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110341/getting-started-developing-for-sharepoint) question for links to more resources to help get you started. I strongly recommend getting a good grounding in how SharePoint works first. It takes more effort initially but will save you a lot of time and confusion later. A good book to start with is [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link, it's a beginners guide of how to develop for SharePoint using VS2008:

[Beginning SharePoint Web Part Development](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Beginning-SharePoint-Web-Part-Development/)

This article should cover all you need to get along. Good luck! :)